# Blender Video Quality dropping during render

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine

I am trying to create a render from a simple scene animation I have created in blender.

This is my first time using blender so I do not know alot but I have set the video to mp4:

[image]

However everytime I render a video file, despite each frame displaying perfectly on the screen when rendereding, The video quality of the mp4 is perfect for the first second, then immediately drops:

Before (1st frame):
[image]

After (30 frames in)
[image]

I have tried rendering videos of different length, I have also tried changing render settings to AVI etc but have not been able to make any difference.

Can somebody please point me the right direction?

Comment: Are you exporting scene directly or dealing with rendered image sequence from VSE? Because rendering scene straight to video is a bad practice, especially 10k frames in lossless.

Comment: I am unsure I am just clicking the render animation button. I believe straight to video using the settings above. I should also add I only changed to lossless to try and fix the issue above.

Comment: Then try export to PNG sequence and see if there is any quality decrease

Comment: thankyou.  I managed to export 30 frames to an avi file without any quality drop. I guess i must be something to do with the ffmpeg encoder settings and I didnt think to try another format. Thankyou for your help!  :-)